# what kind of data type would street address be?

Tags: database, types, uml

I am doing a UML class diagram and will transfer this over into a database.

I was thinking that it would be a int for the location address but there is also strings for the name of the street.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say string. Not all addresses in all countries will start with a number.

Review how google's geocoding works. It's very verbose.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

It could depend of you decompose a street adress...
I would see a composite data, composed of a string for the location (in France it could be "domaine de la motte", "6", or "6 bis"), a string for the type of the street (an enumeration with an empty choice) and a string for the street name.
It may also be a "huge" string containing all.
Keep also in mind the treatment related to this information, in some case do you need the name of the stret without the location inside this latter? In this case keep separated both information. If you will use the Google Geocoding API use an unique string (your treatments will be easier...).

Answer (score 0):

According to the ISO standard, there are several different address hierarchical levels that are under the street level. Block, building, named house, numbered house, entrance, number of flat, section,... I have modeled it 8 years ago and don't remember all of them now. But there are MANY. Better find some appropriate standard or allow the administrator of the SW to add new ones.